# Laravel: How to properly send notification to multiple users with different url/ in Registration Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-authorization, laravel-authentication

I am trying to send notifications to the user after registration with the default auth of laravel 6. I tried using the notification facade, but it gives the same URL for all emails. I tried using the ->notify, but it gives me the error. By the way, I am using smtp.office365.com

> Expected response code 354 but got code "503", with the message "503 5.5.1 Bad sequence of commands"

**RegisterController**

```php
$users = User::where('department_id', $data['department'])
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('manager_level', 'sm1')
            ->orWhere('manager_level', 'sm2')
            ->orWhere('department_level', 'dh');
    })->get();

foreach ($users as $u) {
    $u->notify(new ConfirmUser(($u->department_level == 'dh') ? $u->department_level : $u->manager_level));
}
                    }
```

**InConfirmUser**

```
protected $level;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 */
public function __construct($level)
{
    $this->level = $level;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Confirm User')
        ->greeting("Dear {$notifiable->name},")
        ->line('Please click the button below to confirm that the concerned user is your staff')
        ->action('Confirm User', url('/').$this->level)
        ->line('If you did not know the concerend staff, no further action is required.');
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        //
    ];
}
```

Comment: try `url('').'/'.$this->department`

Comment: @Vibha Chosla the problem persists

Comment: what are you actually doing? just confirming someone's email address?

Comment: Can you tell us, how many `$users` are proceeded in your loop? 

Comment: make sure `$this->department` has a value

Comment: Check my answer you are writing `$u->deparment` without a `t`!

Comment: @Paladin the $users count is 3 and that is the maximum count.

Comment: @lagbox not just to confirm the email address. I need to let the department to confirm if the concerned user is his/her staff. So, the Verify Email address is sent and Confirmations will be sent to different users.

Comment: @thmspl the department is spelled correctly in my code

Comment: but you don't have anything unique in that URL to distinguish the user being verified, unless there can only be 1 user in a department (and that url probably isn't correct) or is this just a link to some page where they can see a bunch of users to verify?

Comment: @VibhaChosla the department always have a value

Comment: @lagbox there is actually, the columns are manager_level and department_level. if the user have values in department_level. I must have a URL for that. If the user have values in manager_level and again, I must have a URL for that User

Comment: but, have you confirmed that by using `dd()` or `echo` it has value wherever you are using it ?

Comment: show the definition for this route you are linking to

Comment: @lagbox I mean, after registering, the concerned user must be confirmed by their bosses using Confirm Button in the email

Comment: @lagbox ughh  what a headache, I have not created the route, but what I have in mind is localhost/confirmUser?token=$token

Comment: Have you tried your code with some other smtp (like mailtrap), so you we can figure out if it's the code or the smtp doing wrong things?

Comment: then what is the url to deparment for? ... this really doesn't make sense, there is no token in your mail message

Comment: @lagbox i am sorry. I edited it now. Honestly, I have not created the route yet. I used the Notification Facade but it sent me the same Email. I dont know how to set the URL so it will have a different token.

Comment: @lagbox in Mailbox, the Confirm User button's url came with "/dh" or "/sm1" and 'etc. but i coudnt find the Verify Email Address that must be sent together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error message change the value of `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` to `tls` in your configuration file and also make sure the `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` is exactly your Office365 email adress.

Tell us more about the `->department` property. Isn't it possible that the department can be the same? Or is it `null` in the mail?

In the code you've wrote `$u->deparment` without a `t`. So change it to this:

```
u->notify(new ConfirmUser($u->department));
```

This could eventually solve your problem.

Comment: the MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS is the same as my email address and MAIL_ENCRYPTION is set to tls. The mail is sent to users with the same department as the registering user. The mail content is the same except for the url('/'). I need to have a different URL because I will be setting different tokens for each recipient.

Comment: So then explain more about this department attribute. How do you store it, DB, controller and much more. Theres not enough informations so that somebody could now whats the problem. It has nothing to do with the notification facade. The problem is that your department property has always the same value.

Comment: I checcked the mailbox and found out that the default verify email address is not found in the mailbox. What could've happened?

Comment: What do you mean with the default verify email address? Please post also your email configurations (Except your password).

Comment: in laravel i made php artisan make:auth so when I register a verify email is sent after registration. When I checked the mailbox, the mails sent were only 3 using the Notification::send($users, new ConfirmUser(...));. The Verify Email is not sent and the error Bad sequence of commands is given as a response.